# nhibernate query optimisation

Tags: nhibernate, linq-to-nhibernate

I've this query :

```
var resQuery = (from pan in session.Query<Pan>()
    orderby pan.AdnMonture.Marque.Nom select pan).ToList<Pan>();
```

The Pan object reference several other object :

```
<many-to-one name="TypeMonture" column="IDType_Monture" cascade="save-update" not-null="true" />
<many-to-one name="AgeMonture" column="IDAge_Monture" cascade="save-update" not-null="true" />
<many-to-one name="SexeMonture" column="IDSexe_Monture" cascade="save-update" not-null="true" />
<many-to-one name="NatureMonture" column="IDNature_Monture" cascade="save-update" not-null="true" />
<many-to-one name="MatiereVerre" column="IDMatiere_Verre" cascade="save-update" />
<many-to-one name="TypeCouleurVerre" column="IDType_Couleur_Verre" cascade="save-update" />
<many-to-one name="CouleurVerre" column="IDCouleur_Verre" cascade="save-update" />
<many-to-one name="ClasseVerre" column="IDClasse_Verre" cascade="save-update" />
<many-to-one name="MontageMonture" column="IDMontage_Monture" cascade="save-update" not-null="true" />
<many-to-one name="BaseMonture" column="IDBase_Monture" cascade="save-update" not-null="true" />
<many-to-one name="CharniereMonture" column="IDCharniere_Monture" cascade="save-update" />
<many-to-one name="BrancheFormeMonture" column="IDBranche_Forme_Monture" cascade="save-update" />
<many-to-one name="BrancheEpaisseurMonture" column="IDBranche_Epaisseur_Monture" cascade="save-update" />
<many-to-one name="TenonPositionMonture" column="IDTenon_Position_Monture" cascade="save-update" not-null="true" />
<many-to-one name="TenonTailleMonture" column="IDTenon_Taille_Monture" cascade="save-update" not-null="true" />
<many-to-one name="FormeMonture" column="IDForme_Monture" cascade="save-update" not-null="true" />
```

And I need sometimes to have the value of each items, ex :

```
foreach (var pan in resQuery)
{
  var test = pan.TypeMonture.Name
  // and more ...
}
```

I've sometimes about 100 result in that query, and I can have about 1k query for this single page.
Is there any solution to avoid that ? (other than stored procedure)

Regards

**Edit**

The Mathieu solution worked but I simplified the case for the example.
And I've this error :

```
A fetch request must be a simple member access expression of the kind o => o.Related; 'pan.Adn.Fabricant' is too complex.
Nom du paramètre : relatedObjectSelector
```

My Pan object reference a Adn object.

```
<many-to-one name="AdnMonture" column="IDADN_Mont" cascade="save-update" not-null="true" />
```

This Adn object reference all the data I presented before. (cf. the hbm.xml before)

Is there any other solution for this case ?
Maybe with join ?

**Edit 2**

I tryed to use ThenFetch

```
return (from pan in session.Query<PanierMonture>()
  .Fetch(pan => pan.AdnMonture)
  .ThenFetch(adn => adn.Fabricant)
  .ThenFetch(adn => adn.Reference)
  .ThenFetch(adn => adn.Marque)
  orderby pan.AdnMonture.Marque.Nom
  select pan).ToList<PanierMonture>();
```

the first ThenFirst works
But the second is blocked by intellisence.
I use the Fabricant object.
So I tryied that :

```
return (from pan in session.Query<PanierMonture>()
  .Fetch(pan => pan.AdnMonture)
  .ThenFetch(adn => adn.Fabricant)
  .Then(adn => adn.Reference)
  .Then(adn => adn.Marque)
  orderby pan.AdnMonture.Marque.Nom
  select pan).ToList<PanierMonture>();
```

But again it doesn't work. intellisense don't give me the adn object

I found this workaround :

```
        return (from pan in session.Query<PanierMonture>()
                .Fetch(pan => pan.AdnMonture)
                .ThenFetch(adn => adn.Fabricant)
                .Fetch(pan => pan.AdnMonture)
                .ThenFetch(adn => adn.Marque)
                .Fetch(pan => pan.AdnMonture)
                .ThenFetch(adn => adn.Reference)
                .Fetch(pan => pan.AdnMonture)
                .ThenFetch(adn => adn.Coloris)
                .Fetch(pan => pan.AdnMonture)
                .ThenFetch(adn => adn.TailleMonture)
                orderby pan.AdnMonture.Marque.Nom
                select pan).ToList<PanierMonture>();
```

Is it correct ?
The generated sql query is a bit strange :

```
select ..... from Panier_Monture paniermont0_ left outer join ADN_Monture adnmonture1_ on paniermont0_.IDADN_Mont=adnmonture1_.IDADN_Monture left outer join Fabricant fabricant2_ on adnmonture1_.IDFabricant=fabricant2_.IDFabricant left outer join ADN_Monture adnmonture3_ on paniermont0_.IDADN_Mont=adnmonture3_.IDADN_Monture left outer join Marque marque4_ on adnmonture3_.IDMarque=marque4_.IDMarque left outer join ADN_Monture adnmonture5_ on paniermont0_.IDADN_Mont=adnmonture5_.IDADN_Monture left outer join Reference reference6_ on adnmonture5_.IDReference=reference6_.IDReference left outer join ADN_Monture adnmonture7_ on paniermont0_.IDADN_Mont=adnmonture7_.IDADN_Monture left outer join Coloris coloris8_ on adnmonture7_.IDColoris=coloris8_.IDColoris left outer join ADN_Monture adnmonture9_ on paniermont0_.IDADN_Mont=adnmonture9_.IDADN_Monture left outer join Taille_Monture taillemont10_ on adnmonture9_.IDTaille=taillemont10_.IDTaille left outer join ADN_Monture adnmonture11_ on paniermont0_.IDADN_Mont=adnmonture11_.IDADN_Monture left outer join Marque marque12_ on adnmonture11_.IDMarque=marque12_.IDMarque order by marque12_.Nom asc
```

The table AdnMonture is repeated each times ?
Is there a chance of problem ?

Regards and again thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See this answer : [Eager load while using Linq in NHibernate 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2075048/eager-load-while-using-linq-in-nhibernate-3)

```
var resQuery = (from pan in session.Query<Pan>()
    .Fetch(p => p.TypeMonture)
    .Fetch(p => p.AgeMonture)
    .Fetch(p => p.Adn ).ThenFetch( a => a.Fabricant )// .. etc
orderby pan.AdnMonture.Marque.om select pan).ToList<Pan>();
```

Now your linked entities will be fetched and you won't have SELECT N+1 problems

Comment: thank you mathieu for your answer mathieu, it worked with the case I presented but not in the real case. I edited the question.